# How to make selected value different than options value in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, select

How can I make the selected value different than the values given in options with select in AngularJS. 
Here is what I have now:
[image]

What I want to achieve is, to display the selected value as "EN", but the options inside to be "English", "Italian",...

Below is my HTML Code for the select element:

```
<select class="select-language d-md-none d-inline-block" ng-options="lang.Lang_Code for lang in languagesMenu" 
        ng-model="language" ng-change="changeLanguage()" ng-cloak>
</select>
```

This is my JavaScript for the languagesMenu:

```
// navigation languages
    $scope.languagesMenu = [
        {
            Language: "English",
            Country: "USA",
            Code: "en/us/",
            Lang_Code: "en"
        }, {
            Language: "Italian",
            Country: "IT",
            Code: "it/it/",
            Lang_Code: "it"
        }
    ]
```

And this is the changeLanguage function:

```
// change language 
    $scope.changeLanguage = function () {
        $window.open($scope.language.Code, '_self');
    }
```

How can I make the options to be the "Language" from the JSON array, and the selected value to be the "Lang_Code"?

Answer (score 0):

The following **snippet** might help where we:

- use `ng-options="item.Language for item in languagesMenu "` to select which property within the languagesMenu object gets displayed
- and then we use `$scope.selectedName.Code` which takes the `Code` property from our selected object (thanks to `ng-model`) to go to redirect to the relevant page

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.languagesMenu = [{
      Language: "English",
      Code: "us/"
    },
    {
      Language: "Italian",
      Code: "it/"
    },
    {
      Language: "Chinese",
      Code: "cn/"
    }
  ];
  $scope.changeLanguage = function() {
    $window.open($scope.selectedName.Code, '_self');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="item.Language for item in languagesMenu " ng-change="changeLanguage()">
  </select>
  Selected language: {{selectedName.Code }}
</div>
```